# How to effectively find flights from Oslo, Norway?

Tags: air-travel, budget, norway, oslo

I encountered a problem that it is hard to find cheap flights from Oslo, both `Oslo(OSL)` and `Sandefjord(TRR)`. There are many low-costs such as Wizzair, Norwegian, Ryanair but always when I want to travel there are almost no or no options.

Is there any aggregates, channels or anything that can help me find flights cheaper, easier and faster?

Comment: Just did Oslo to London on SkyScanner for March and its £31 return with RyanAir at the time of writing this comment, around 341.20 Norwegian Krone. That's very cheap https://www.skyscanner.net/transport/flights/oslo/lond/190315/190318/?adults=1&children=0&adultsv2=1&childrenv2=&infants=0&cabinclass=economy&rtn=1&preferdirects=false&outboundaltsenabled=false&inboundaltsenabled=false&ref=home#results

Comment: @BritishSam It is a good option and England is super cheap, except that England, Ireland have many limitations for certain nationalities. At least, this is the case with me. I can visit almost any country, except of these 2.

Comment: Where are you looking to fly to?

Comment: Ideally, to the countries that I have never been such as Protugal, Spain, France, Austria, Alabania, Italy, Slovenia, Slovakia, Iceland, Sweden, Belgium, Greece, Malta and this is only Europe list.

Comment: Same dates to Barcelona are only £74. Check out SkyScanner and Google flights https://www.skyscanner.net/transport/flights/oslo/bcn/190315/190318/?adults=1&children=0&adultsv2=1&childrenv2=&infants=0&cabinclass=economy&rtn=1&preferdirects=false&outboundaltsenabled=false&inboundaltsenabled=false&ref=home#results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just from the top of my head you have [Google Flights](https://www.google.com/flights), [KAYAK](https://www.kayak.pt), [SkyScanner](https://www.skyscanner.com), [Expedia](https://www.expedia.com/), [Momondo](https://www.momondo.com) and [Hopper](https://www.hopper.com/). Although there's probably a ton more of this kind of flights aggregator websites.

I personally use mostly Google Flights and KAYAK but you should try them to see which one fits you best.

EDIT: Just made a querie for return flights from Oslo airports to destinations across europe for 1 week during the next 6 months and found plenty of cheap [flights](https://www.google.com/flights?hl=en#flt=/m/05l64..2019-01-03*./m/05l64.2019-01-07;c:EUR;e:1;ls:1w;sd:0;er:449847798.-18916016.644849635.332646484;t:e&spf=1545147326700).

Comment: I have used all of them. I also have used `finn.no` Norwegian version. It is possible to find good flights but it takes ages because all of them by nature slow. Don't you know how to overcome these limitations?

Comment: @DmytroChasovskyi check my edit with a flight querie from Oslo on Google Flights